# Display 10 unique pictures from source.unsplash.com inside a ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using *ngFor to repeat a img tag trying to show 10 unique pictures from the unsplash API. My code looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of myArray; let index = index">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src={{a}}>
</div>
</div>
```

myArray consist of 10 strings with the same link: https://source.unsplash.com/category/x where x is taken from a user input field. An example of x could be nature or food. Every time I go to https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature I get a different picture displayed but in my app it shows the same picture 10 times.

It seems like my app is only accessing the link one time and then repeats the image 10 times, how do i make it so the 10 images are all unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

`<img src={{a.url}}>`

where a is each item in your **myArray** array.

Comment: this makes sense and it helped, thanks! but i still got the problem of not having 10 unique pictures showing. I have now edited my original post

Comment: can u do 2 things? 1) Provide ur component code as well and 
2) Check page if the tag has the same url. 
The best way is to show ur code in github or plunker so it is easier to spot the problem.

Comment: here is a plunker of my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/XHtbBpwVxKemXBfmP6dQ

Comment: Ok. The problem is really in your searchbox function. 1) The **onSearch** receives a text where, in your searchbox  search event pass an event to the onSearch function.But that's not the actual problem. 

2) The real problem is in your loop, you push the same url 10 times and therefore, even if you did ```<img src={{a.url}}>```. U will alway see the same image. U need to modify your loop, such that it will change some variable on ur url, so that the images will display uniquely.

Comment: thanks Gavin for the help, seems like i need a different approach

Comment: Just another comment. 

if you want to implement a searchbox. You probably can do such a way that upon submit the search field. a function will append the text  from the search field to your **nyarray**, with that, whenever user submits a search, it will display the new image to ur thumnail section. Another approach, is to use tags, instead of a searchbox.

Answer (score 5):

It's been a few months, but the answer is here:

https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-source-js/issues/9

> You can do that by adding a sig param to the query string. e.g.
>   `https://source.unsplash.com/random?sig=123` It doesn't matter what the
>   value is (it's ignored on the server-side), just that it's different
>   for every instance on the page.
>
> -aaronklaassen